# Tcp connection closing initiation by server is fevorable?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

According to tcp protocol when ever tcp connection termination is going on, tcp socket of initiator go to following states FIN-WAIT-1, FIN-WAIT-2,TIME-WAIT before connection is completly closed and the tcp socket of other end go to following states CLOSE-WAIT, LAST-ACK, CLOSED before connection is completly closed. 
In our application server is initiating connection termination which leading to server side sockets are waiting in FIN_WAIT2 state infinitely, due to this connections made by clients are dropped by server because of unavailability of ports.
Is connection termination initiated by clients is favourable or not?

Answer (score 3):

Initiating termination from the client can be favorable because it prevents the server from going to TIME_WAIT. Your problem is different.

A socket in FIN_WAIT2 is "half open": the client side can still send data and you can read it, but you can't send anything back. The socket will stay in this state until the client closes its socket, or the server resets the connection.

So it sounds like your clients are simply not closing their sides of the connections.